# Which V2 .onion services are still running?

Tags: onion-services

Can you share any V2 .onion hidden services that are still up and running?

I am doing a research project and looking into how difficult it is for an older Tor client to reach a V2 hidden service now that the number of HSDirs supporting V2 is very low.

***I am aware V2 is unsafe and no longer supported. I am solely looking into the current situation.***

Comment: I don't know of any, but it might be easiest to use an old tor version and try running a v2 service yourself. Support for v2 services was removed in tor 0.4.6, and there are not many relays still running a version < 0.4.6 (around [950 relays](https://metrics.torproject.org/versions.html) out of 6500), so it might be difficult to get a v2 service to even bootstrap at all.

Comment: Hi @Steve. What would be necessary, i.e. which stages of the rendez vous protocol make it difficult, to bootstrap a simple V2 hidden service?

My reasoning: it is currently unlikely for the hidden service to choose introduction points running a tor version < 0.4.6 and also it is not always possible for the OR to send a hidden service descriptor to a HSDir still supporting V2Dir.

Is this a correct reasoning? Am I forgetting any other challenges?